# Как подключить функцию JQueryui к вновь созданому элименту

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Собственно вот так создаю

```
$("#addLesson").click(function(){
    var inputVal=$("#idLesson").val();

    if(inputVal){
        var divStart = "<div class='well col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 draggable'>"+inputVal+"<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove del'></span></div>";
        $(blockLesson).append(divStart);        
    }
});
```

вот так пытаюсь подключить

```
$('#blockLesson').on( 'click',"div",draggable());
```

консоль дает такую ошибку

> ReferenceError: draggable is not defined

и вот так пытаюсь

```
$('#blockLesson').on( 'draggable',"div");
```

и вот так

```
$('#blockLesson').on( 'click',"div",function(){$(this).draggable()});
```

ни чего не получается.

Comment: что за функция _draggable_? не исключено, что надо просто опустить `()`

Comment: @Grundy вот собствено сама функция https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Стоит все-таки сходить по этой ссылке и посмотреть _как используется_ эта _функция_ :-) Могу сразу сказать, что в примере в вопросе - какая-то совсем другая функция _draggable_, никак не связанная с той, что по ссылке

Comment: @Grundy вот я и хочу понять как правильно подключить эту функцию к вновь созданному элимену

Comment: @Grundy я полностью суть вопроса изменил так мне кажется будет правильнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная функция *инициализирует* плагин. Если его надо инициализировать на *новом* элементе, то надо получить этот элемент и инициализировать.

В данном месте собирается html

```
var divStart = "<div class='well col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 draggable'>"+inputVal+"<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove del'></span></div>";
```

Вместо этого тут сразу можно создавать jQuery объект

```
var divStart = $("<div class='well col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 draggable'>"+inputVal+"<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove del'></span></div>");
```

К которому уже можно применить указанную функцию

```
divStart.draggable();
```